# No such package '@com_google_javascript_closure_library//closure/goog/soy'

Tags: bazel, google-closure, bazel-rules

I met following error:

`ERROR: /home/lemito/cpp-starter-kit/cpp/sources/clo/BUILD:35:19: no such package '@com_google_javascript_closure_library//closure/goog/soy': BUILD file not found in directory 'closure/goog/soy' of external repository @com_google_javascript_closure_library. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '//sources/clo:greeter_lib' ERROR: Analysis of target '//sources/clo:greeter_lib' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed`

My files:
https://github.com/lemito/my-monorepo (github | project in sources/clo)

I tried changing the loading of external dependencies from http to git

Comment: How can this error reproduced? by  `bazel build //...`? Add more details to your question

Comment: I was able to get rid of the error myself by downloading and installing into the project folder closure-library and rules_closure . If there is any detail missing, please ask